# How to run Zeppelin in Visualisation Dev Mode?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am on windows platform and I have been trying to run Zeppelin in Visualisation Dev Mode for testing a simple hello-world Helium Visualisation plugin, but with no good results. I have downloaded Zeppelin 0.7.X binary for windows and Zeppelin server is running on localhost:8081 port.

To run Zeppelin in visualisation-dev-mode, I downloaded Zeppelin 0.7.x master, inside which i can find zeppelin-web.  The documentation says the following commands are to be executed:

```
cd zeppelin-web
yarn run visdev
```

But when I run the same, the yarn command picks up the command:

> "HELIUM_BUNDLE_DEV=true webpack-dev-server --hot"

from the scripts present in package.json file and throws $HELIUM_BUNDLE_DEV is not a recognized command. Also if I remove first argument it says $webpack-dev-server is not a recognized command.

Can anybody help me out on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try replace 
`HELIUM_BUNDLE_DEV = true webpack-dev-server -hot` 
on
`set HELIUM_BUNDLE_DEV = true webpack-dev-server -hot`

On Windows environment variables are set this way `set VAR_NAME = var_value`

Comment: Thanks for replying. But that did not work either. Now it says true is not a recognized command. My question is, to test simple hello-world helium application should i run zeppelin in visualisation dev mode? I tried all other options by placing packages in a folder and then by providing absolute artifact path in the helloworld.json package file inside helium folder. This brings plugins under the available-helium-plugins in the UI, if I enable it, it does not appear on the notebook. !

Comment: No. You do not have to run the development mode to enable helium visualization. In this mode, the helium package will be re-assembled after each page reload (if you connected to the dev port, default 9000). 
You managed to run an example from a folder `zeppelin-examples` ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yeah, I tried running simple examples from zeppelin-example, but not with good results. Simple hello world and horizontalbar visualisation too did not work. It says 'Can't get module name and version of package helloworld'. Can you please tell me how exactly the path of artifact need to be specified in package.json and also the best place to place the module?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue as in this link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2097

Comment: Do you have any good reasons to use version 0.7? Recently, the release of 0.8, and in it when creating helium packets there are fewer errors.

Comment: Hello.. Yes. I downloaded the latest binary of Zeppelin (0.8). It worked. But not right in the first attempt. It tries to install npm first. Then it installs yarn. Then pulls the packages from npm registry. For me, firstly npm installation failed. Then yarn installation failed. Trying 2 - 3 times, the both npm and yarn were installed successfully. Then our helium plugins were installed. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I'm glad that you did it.